# sets of random numbers between lists of lows and highs

Tags: python, random

Hi – new to python (use R normally) – want to pick a set of four random values (into a list) between the successive pairs of values from low and high

```
low = [-20.0, -10.0, 0.0, 0.0]
high = [20.0, 10.0, 1.0, 0.7]
```

I understand how to do it for single pair of values in each list
`random.randint(low[1], high[1])`

How can I create list of four random values between each set of values in low and high. In R it could be via lapply etc.

Many thanks for guidance (getting over small hurdles like this at mo)
Malcolm

I used `random.randint(low[1], high[1])` - but struggled with R based lapply version

Comment: I should stress I want python solution - have used lapply in R - want to learn python version of this (its probably quite easy - so sorry)

Comment: Hello, if I understand correctly, you want a set of four values between `low[0] .. high[0], low[1] .. high[1], low[2] .. high[2], low[3] .. high[3]`? But you need floats, not integers, right?

Comment: yes floats - sorry yes

Comment: it will be more than four numbers for bigger problems - so some automated way where have n to find - each with known bounds on them

Comment: Found a solution
rdnlst = [random.uniform(low[1], high[1])]
for i in range(2, 4):
    rdnlst.append(random.uniform(low[i], high[i]))

Comment: I am by no means a Python expert, but here's a suggestion : `MyList = [ random.uniform(x, y) for x,y in zip(Low, High) ]`

Comment: As a side note: arrays are 0-based in Python.